# The point $c$ from mean value theorem

Tags: calculus

The **mean value theorem** says that

> Let $a<b$ be real numbers. If $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous on the closed interval $[a,b]$ and differentiable on open interval $(a,b)$, then
> there exists $c\in (a,b)$ such that
> \begin{align*}
>          f(b)-f(a)=f'(c) (b-a) 
>        \end{align*}

**My question/answer**: Suppose now that $f$ is differentiable on $[a,b]$. Can the point $c$ be an endpoint of the interval $[a,b]$? Since the mean value theorem is a corollary of Rolle's theorem, it follows that $c$ cannot be an endpoint of the interval $[a,b]$. Otherwise, the function $f$ would be constant. Am I right? Does exist a nonconstant function such that $c$ be an endpoint of the interval $[a,b]$?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can consider the function $y=x$ restricted on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Oh. the function $f(x)=a\cdot x,a\in\mathbb{R}$ also works, no?

Comment: @stefano I think so.